# Problems with PHP/CSS in IE but not Chrome

Tags: php, css

I recently split my HTML site in PHP so I can make global changes more easily and get ready for a possible migration to Wordpress.
The HTML version works with IE and Chrome. Now that I split the site in PHP it only works in Chrome. In IE a lot of the CSS elemets are missing.
Is this a common mistake I can fix?
Remember the same HTML code works in IE so it has to be something I am doing wrong in the PHP version. I have the same issue with another website I am working on. Maybe there is a special character I am missing?

Website URL:
http://dursoboxing.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of that comment right at the start. I think IE is a little shirty about having anything, even whitespace before the doctype declaration, and not having a doctype does much worse things to IE than it does to any other browser.

Comment: IE _is_ shirty about having space before the doctype. Silly, silly IE.

Comment: I wish I could kiss you. :)
I only changed the index.php 
Seems to be working right?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some unclosed HTML tags in partial views? Modern browsers are quite smart and try to predict which tags to close first and later on.

Comment: They only do this to keep compatibility with the crappily written, older pages. IMO, they should become a lot stricter.

Comment: I just cant wrap my head around the idea that different browsers can show the same code differently.

Comment: @JamWaffles I totally agree but... how to convince some people that their "well formed HTML" isn't as well formed as they think :D ?

Comment: @veritas Spam them with links to the W3C validator and docs _constantly_ until they read and use them ;-)